# Spectral Radius of Hilbert-Schmidt Integral Operator

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory, compact-operators

I was wondering if there were any easy results regarding the spectral radius of a Hilbert-Schmidt operator. The Hilbert-Schmidt integral operator is defined by
$$ Tf(x) = \int k(x,y) f(y) \: dy . $$
I'm guessing there is not an easy general form for the spectral radius of this operator, since in the case I'm dealing with, Gelfand's formula yields something of the form
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \Big|\Big| \int k^n(x,y) g(y) \: dy \Big|\Big|^{1/n}$$
where $k^n(x,y)$ can be a rather complicated and varied expression. Nevertheless, a simple result that holds in general would be very useful.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: One result that you may be aware of is that when the integral operator is self adjoint as a map from $L^2\to L^2$ (so the kernel k(x,y) is real and symmetric in its variables), then the spectral radius is equal to the $L^2\to L^2$ operator norm of the operator.

Comment: Thanks! These are the types of results that are helpful, but unfortunately I can't use the symmetry property in my case :(